# Массив указателей на функции-члены

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Задача заключается в том, что бы в `private` надо создать статическую переменную символьного типа, в `protected` просто переменные вещественного типа, в `public` массив указателей на функции-члены класса.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {    
    private:
        static char x;
    protected:
        char q = 1;
        char w = 2;
        char e = 3;

    public:
        void func1(void){
            cout<<"func 1"<<endl;
        };

        void func2(void){
            cout<<"func 2"<<endl;
        };

        void (*func[])(void) = {func1, func2};

};

int main() {
    A ob;

    for(int i=0; i < sizeof(ob.func); i++)
    {
         ob.func[i]();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот ошибки:

```
19  39  C:\Users\User\Desktop\ГЊГҐГ°Г±Г®Гў\laBa.cpp [Error] too many initializers for 'void (* [0])()'
19  39  C:\Users\User\Desktop\ГЊГҐГ°Г±Г®Гў\laBa.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'A::func1' from type 'void (A::)()' to type 'void (*)()'
19  39  C:\Users\User\Desktop\ГЊГҐГ°Г±Г®Гў\laBa.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'A::func2' from type 'void (A::)()' to type 'void (*)()'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. C++ не поддерживает синтаксис с неявным определением размера массива при объявлении члена класса с in-class инициализатором. Размер массива надо указывать явно.
2. Указатель на функцию-член класса имеет тип `ReturnType (ClassType::*)(ParameterTypes)`, а у вас объявлены указатели на обычные функции.
3. Формирование указателя на функцию-член класса всегда требует явного использования оператора `&` и указания квалифицированного имени функции.

   ```
   void (A::*func[2])(void) = { &A::func1, &A::func2 };
   ```
4. Синтаксис вызова функции через указатель также неверен. В данном случае это будет

   ```
   (ob.*ob.func[i])();
   ```
5. Почему цикл по `i` вдруг итерирует до `sizeof(ob.func)`???